# jquery $.ajax backup url

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I wrote this code to get a language file for the page depending on browser language:

```
$.ajax({
      'async': false,
      'global': false,
      'url': "./languages/"+navigator.language.substring(0,2)+".json",
      'dataType': "json",
      'success': function (testo) {
        $.each( testo, function(originalstring, newstring){
        $('body').html($('body').html().replace(originalstring, newstring));
        });
      }
  });
```

Is there a simple way to manage a "file not found" error and consequently load a default language json file (i.e. english)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use error callback of ajax

```
$.ajax({
  async: false,
  global: false,
  url: "./languages/"+navigator.language+".json",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (testo) {
    $.each( testo, function(originalstring, newstring){
    $('body').html($('body').html().replace(originalstring, newstring));
    }
  },
 error:function( obj, textStatus, errorThrown){
    //load default lang file here
 }
```

});

Comment: You mean I should write a nested $.ajax, don't you? It seems extremely ugly to me, I hope I didn't understand!

Answer (score 1):

```
        $.ajax({
              'async': false,
              'global': false,
              'url': "./languages/"+navigator.language+".json",
              'dataType': "json",
               complete: function(e, xhr, settings){
                   if(e.status === 404){

                    call the same function by passing the language as english

                   }
                },
              'success': function (testo) {
                $.each( testo, function(originalstring, newstring){
                $('body').html($('body').html().replace(originalstring, newstring));
                });
              }
          });
```